# Customizing immutable types in Python

Tags: python, immutability, delegation

Let's say I want a custom `frozenset` with 2 elements, that iterates, hashes, compares, and has various other nice operations as a frozenset, but prints differently.

```
>>> p = edge(5, 7)
>>> p == edge(7, 5)
True
>>> p
edge(5, 7)
```

I can inherit, or I can delegate, but in neither case I get what I want.

If I inherit literally, there seems to be no way I can write `__init__`, because my parent is immutable. I *can* just write:

```
class edge:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        return frozenset({a, b})
```

but then I get a proper frozenset and cannot customize its `__repr__`, which is what I wanted to do. I cannot make `super()` to work here in any nice way.

If I delegate, I can override `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, but none of them really works when for example `__iter__` is sought. I guess special methods are too special here. The only solution I currently have is to manually delegate every special method I can think of, but surely there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: I am unclear what you want to do.  Do you just want to change `__repr__`, or do you also want to change `__init__`, too?  Because you don't need to override `__init__` if you only want to change `__repr__`.

Comment: Changing `__repr__` was priority. But I thought I might as well change the construction of new edges to remove unnecessary {}s, when I'm writing a new class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid me. It works now. If someone wants to know how to do it, here it is:

```
class pair(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        return super().__new__(cls, {a, b})
    def __repr__(self):
        a, b = sorted(self)
        return "{} & {}".format(a, b)
```

The error was that I called `super().__new__({a, b})` thinking that it will transmogrify my `cls` in the same way it does with `self`, when called without arguments. Of course, `__new__` being implicitly classmethod didn't help. :-)